# Python Script to replace multiple string with a mapping table

Tags: python

We are currently doing a project to translate a PS2 game and I'm using Python for a lot of stuff.

I have a table mapping specific letter, `[Tag]` to a series of Hex values.

`mappingDict = { '[Sign_5]': '0D80000000', 'H':'48', 'e':'65', 'l':'6C', 'g':'4D'}`

Then I have a list of text like this :
`textList = [ '[Sign_5]Hell', 'He' ]`

For my game, I need to convert the text to HEX values to calculate the number of bytes it occupied.

`EndResult = [ '0D8000000048656C6C', '4865' ]`

Of course, the difficult part is we have to prioritize the longest string first.
i.e : we can't replace the `'g'` in `[Sign_5]` by `4D`. The whole word need to be replaced by `0D80000000`.

I'm trying to find the most efficient way of doing this.

Thank you for any suggestions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just sort the keys by length before searching each element of your list.

```
mappingDict = { '[Sign_5]': '0D80000000', 'H':'48', 'e':'65', 'l':'6C', 'g':'4D'}
keys=sorted(list(mappingDict.keys()),key=lambda x: len(x))[::-1]
textList = [ '[Sign_5]Hell', 'He' ]
outList=[]
for tt in textList:
  v=tt
  for k in keys:
    if k in v:
      v=v.replace(k,mappingDict[k])
  outList.append(v)

print(outList)
```

This gives the desired output.

```
['0D8000000048656C6C', '4865']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add two more options:

1. A similar answer to above, but using a function and list apprehension:

```py
mapping = [('[Sign_5]','0D80000000'), ('H','48'), ('e','65'), ('l','6C'), ('g','4D')]
textList = ['[Sign_5]Hell','He']

def textToHex(text):
    for k, v in mapping: 
        text = text.replace(k, v)
    return text

hexList = [textToHex(text) for text in textList]

print(hexList)
```

2. Using the package Pandas and a dictionary:

```py
import pandas as pd

textList = pd.Series(['[Sign_5]Hell','He'])
mappingDict = {'\[Sign_5\]':'0D80000000','H':'48','e':'65','l':'6C','g':'4D'}

hexList = textList.replace(mappingDict, regex=True).to_list()

print(hexList)
```